# ExoPlayer. How to specify timeout to loading HLS manifest?

Tags: android, timeout, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How to specify timeout to load HLS manifest with ExoPlayer?

HLS manifest loading ignore option

```kotlin
DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
    .setConnectTimeoutMs(timeout)
    .setReadTimeoutMs(timeout)
```

applies only to chunks loading.